# How can I see if an object is inside the volume rendering of the camera?

Tags: python, camera

i have a project with the stereo camera.
I want delete all the objects outside the volume of rendering of the camera.

I have all the parameters of the camera and i have calculated the near plane, the far plane and the convergence plane (i know all the vertices).

But i don't understand How can I see if an object is inside the volume rendering of the camera.

I know how put the objects in the camera's coordinate system

```
camera.matrix_world.inverted() * obj.location
```

Some ideas?

p.s.
i have see this question:
[What are the formulas to define the camera's view cone?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/27937/what-are-the-formulas-to-define-the-cameras-view-cone)
it's good but it does not work very well

Comment: [This answer at so](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29720938/2684771) may be what you want. you need to choose what you test, an objects centre or bound_box?

Comment: Also this: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6891/does-camera-view-frame-return-the-correct-size-of-near-clip-plane. Note that there will be a new feature in upcoming Blender 2.76: https://developer.blender.org/rB92a3799 ("automatic object culling based on whether
object is visible in the frame or not").

Comment: thanks for the reply.
the [link](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6891/does-camera-view-frame-return-the-correct-size-of-near-clip-plane) posted by @CoDEmanX is perfect!
I solved my problem, thanks

Now i have this problem: how do I access the data of the single camera (left and right) that make up the central camera?

Comment: You mean in a 3D stereo camera setup? Do you want to calculate each camera individually, a single virtual central camera, or max of left and right?