# Stereoscopic camera: how to see objects visible only from the right and left camera

Tags: python, camera

Previously, I've asked this question: [How can I see if an object is inside the volume rendering of the camera?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/36299/how-can-i-see-if-an-object-is-inside-the-volume-rendering-of-the-camera) and I had found the solution thanks to this post: [Does Camera.view_frame() return the correct size of near clip plane?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6891/does-camera-view-frame-return-the-correct-size-of-near-clip-plane)

The line code `x, y, z = world_to_camera_view(sce, cam, mat * v.co)` is perfect for found the objects are visible from the central camera but it excludes items that are only visible from a single camera (camera L or R). **I want to find the objects visible only from the right camera and objects visible only from the left camera.**

A possible solution would be:

1. Delete stereoscopy
2. Move the camera to the right of intercular distance / 2
3. Incline the camera to the z-axis of angle of convergence (easy calculation)
4. Check the visible item with `world_to_camera_view`
5. Repeat for simulate the left camera (move to right and rotate z -angle)
6. Set True the stereoscopy

**But how to eliminate the stereoscopy and have a camera equal to that of the left and right?**

---

I solved my issue by following the steps I listed. Now I have this problem:

If I place the camera on the right of a value (even higher) and then use `world_to_camera_view` the result I get is the same. That tells me that the camera always sees the same objects.

#### Code

```
import bpy
from bpy_extras.object_utils import world_to_camera_view

context = bpy.context
scene = bpy.context.scene
scene.update

def checkIfIsInCameraView(cam, obj):
    for v in obj.data.vertices:
        x, y, z = world_to_camera_view(context.scene, cam, obj.matrix_world * v.co)
        if (0.0 <= x <= 1.0 and 0.0 <= y <= 1.0):
            return True

    return False

#set off stereo
scene.render.use_multiview = False

#creo nuova camera per simulare camera laterale
cameraNormal = scene.camera

#change camera position
cameraNormal.location.x = cameraNormal.location.x - 50.0

for obj in scene.objects:
    if obj.type == 'MESH':
        #print if in camera view
        if checkIfIsInCameraView(cameraNormal, obj):
            print(obj)

#change camera position
cameraNormal.location.x = cameraNormal.location.x + 100.0

for obj in scene.objects:
    if obj.type == 'MESH':
        #print if in camera view
        if checkIfIsInCameraView(cameraNormal, obj):
            print(obj)

#set on stereo
scene.render.use_multiview = True
scene.update
```

Some tips?

Comment: Do you really expect the difference to be big enough that an object will only be seen in one camera?

Comment: It depends on the settings of the camera and the proximity of the object.
It is a typical case of "window violation" in stereoscopy

Comment: It will depend on how accurate you want to go, using off-axis convergence gives a leaning pyramid for visible volume that increases the error if your using a plain camera as the values get larger. For best results it would mean calculating the visible volume that matches every camera setting.

Comment: Sometimes, you need to use scene.update() once you've modified some properties (location, rotation) of the objects. When the scene is updated, you can use the new values.

Comment: @JonathanChemla. OMG! my bad! really ... I had forgotten the ()
thanks for the help!

Comment: the first time I used scene.update () It is working properly
now if i run again the script don't goes...

Comment: Ok, adding this as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes, you need to use `scene.update()` once you've modified some properties (location, rotation) of the objects. When the scene is updated, you can use the new values.
You forgot the parentheses after the function call :)