# Automatically hide everything out of camera view?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, animation, objects, camera

I've asked myself if it is possible to **automatically hide everything** and every object while rendering an **animation**.

For instance if I had a very **big scene**, like a street in a city, but I only want to render a **small part** of it or a close up shot. I don't want blender to calculate all the vertices and light bounces from all the other objects around even though most of them are **not even in camera view** and don't affect the final image.

If i could tell blender that they are not in camera view so they should be ignored it would save a great amount of rendertime. The only thing I know is that you can use the small camera icon the inspector (or outliner) to tell blender I don't want this to show up in the final image, but this is not exactly what I'm looking for: Is there a way to do that **dynamicly**? Where blender calculates which objects are in camera view and which not by itself. Especially for animations that would be very helpful!

Thank you in advance for your answers,
and sorry for my bad english.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but I think blender and most 3d software does tihs automatically.

Comment: No, Blender doesn't do this automaticaly, and depending on what render engine you use, you might not even want to do that. An object may be offscreen but still contributes relevantly to a rendered image, like cast shadows, light bouces, reflections etc. This may be done in game engines, and other non global illuminated applications, but even then is not at all something trivial to do.

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/45146/how-to-find-all-objects-in-the-cameras-view-with-python

Comment: As pointed out by @DuarteFarrajotaRamos the surrounding elements on the scene, even if outside of the camera view still contribute to the creation of the image. To save time in animation you might want to consider **baking** the materials so that they are much simpler at rendering time. Then yes, you could ignore the elements that are not in camera view (except for any kind of reflections on glossy materials).

Comment: Yes of course there are some light bounces or reflections, but only from the objects nearby. But what if i am rendering an indoor animation and the scene has multiple rooms for example. If objects are out of range from any kind of interaction within camera view then it would be very useless for blender to render them.

Comment: Blender will ignore whatever rays it cannot see. If you are rendering a closed room with no windows, blender will completely ignore the reflections and subsurface scattering transparency of the beautiful roses  bathing in sunlight in the yard that are part of the exterior... As a matter of discipline break down your scene so that it does not contain elements that are not needed.

Comment: could you perhaps use different layers and disable those "not in camera view"...?