# Why Eevee doesn't illuminate more than 128 lights in a scene in real-time?

Tags: eevee-render-engine

I don't know if it is a bug or a limitation of Eevee, but the bigger scenes actually needs more than 128 lights. Also, Eevee doesn't bake more than 64 irradiance volumes. If it is not a bug, is there a culling option how to deactivate those lights and light probes that are behind the cameras, behind any object without a visual of them on the camera? 
Thanks.

Comment: I think the situations where one needs around 128 lights in a scene should be reconsidered. Images are rarely about something else than visual communication and human mind does not process things in these numbers even if they are much more obvious than light sources in an image. 3 to 5 is a good number of things in general. Complex product visualizations may legitimately require more than 5 lights, but the number of light sources that are important in an image should not even approach 128 no matter what render engine is used. If it does in most cases chances are you are doing something wrong.

Answer (score 1):

This is a current limitation:

https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/render/eevee/limitations.html

For your second question look here: [Automatically hide everything out of camera view?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/81386/automatically-hide-everything-out-of-camera-view)