# scripting - zoom camera to view all objects

Tags: scripting

My objects sounds like a bit large, I guess I need to move camera far away from origin (put a sphere there) but if I increase the camera location x value, it will can not see anything.

[image]

```
import bpy
from math import radians,cos,sin,tan
from mathutils import Matrix, Vector, Euler

def clean_objects():
    if len(bpy.data.objects) == 0:
        return
    oldMode = bpy.context.mode
    if oldMode != 'OBJECT':
        bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='OBJECT')

    for o in bpy.data.objects:
        if o.type == 'MESH':
            o.select = True
        else:
            o.select = False
        o.select = True
        #print("%s -> %d"%(o.name,o.select))

    bpy.ops.object.delete()
    if oldMode != 'OBJECT':
        bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode=oldMode)
    return

def dump_objects():
    for ob in bpy.data.objects:
        print(ob.name)
    return

def setOrigin(loc):
    for ob in bpy.data.objects:
       ob.location -= loc
    return

def add_objects():
    m = 16
    n = 12
    h = 96
    outer = 100
    stud_x = 4
    stud_y = 8
    stud_z = 96
    alpha = 30
    for i in range(0,m):
        print(i)
        for j in range(0,n):
            if (i == 0 or i== m-1 or j == 0 or j == n-1):
                bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cube_add()
                bpy.context.object.dimensions = (stud_x,stud_y,h)
                bpy.context.object.location = (16*i,16*j,0)

    bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cube_add()
    bpy.context.object.dimensions = ((m-1)*16 + stud_x,stud_y,stud_x)
    bpy.context.object.location = ((m-1)*16/2,0,(h+stud_x)/2)   
    bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cube_add()
    bpy.context.object.dimensions = ((m-1)*16 + stud_x,stud_y,stud_x)
    bpy.context.object.location = ((m-1)*16/2,(n-1)*16,(h+stud_x)/2)   
    bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cube_add()
    bpy.context.object.dimensions = (stud_x,(n-1)*16,stud_x) # overlap
    bpy.context.object.location = (0,(n-1)*16/2,(h+stud_x)/2)   
    bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cube_add()
    bpy.context.object.dimensions = (stud_x,(n-1)*16,stud_x) # overlap
    bpy.context.object.location = ((m-1)*16,(n-1)*16/2,(h+stud_x)/2)  

    for i in range(0,m):
        bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cube_add()
        bpy.context.object.dimensions = (stud_x,(n-1)*16+2*outer,stud_x)
        bpy.context.object.location = (16*i,(n-1)*16/2,(h+stud_x)/2+stud_x)  

        p = outer + (n-1)*16/2
        bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cube_add()
        bpy.context.object.dimensions = (stud_x,p/cos(radians(alpha)),stud_x)
        bpy.context.object.location = (16*i,p/2 -outer,(h+stud_x)/2+stud_x + p*tan(radians(alpha))/2)  
        bpy.context.object.rotation_euler = (radians(alpha),0,0) 
        bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cube_add()
        bpy.context.object.dimensions = (stud_x,p/cos(radians(alpha)),stud_x)
        bpy.context.object.location = (16*i,p/2 -outer + p,(h+stud_x)/2+stud_x + p*tan(radians(alpha))/2)  
        bpy.context.object.rotation_euler = (radians(180-alpha),0,0) 
    bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_plane_add()
    bpy.context.object.dimensions = (16*(m+5),16*(n+5),10)
    bpy.context.object.location = (16*m/2,16*n/2,-h/2)
    setOrigin(Vector(((m-1)*16/2, (n-1)*16/2, h/2)))    
    return

def add_camera():
    bpy.ops.object.camera_add()
    bpy.context.object.location = (150,50,150)
    bpy.ops.object.lamp_add(type='SPOT')
    bpy.context.object.location = (200,200,200)
    bpy.context.object.dimensions = (200,200,200)
    bpy.ops.curve.primitive_bezier_circle_add(radius=400)

    camera = bpy.data.objects['Camera']
    path = bpy.data.objects['BezierCircle']
    lamp = bpy.data.objects['Spot']

    camera.select = True
    lamp.select = True
    path.select = True

    bpy.context.scene.objects.active = path #parent
    bpy.ops.object.parent_set(type='FOLLOW') #follow path

    bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_uv_sphere_add(size=20, location=(0,0,0))
    target = bpy.context.object;
    camera.constraints.new(type='TRACK_TO').target = target
    camera.constraints["Track To"].track_axis = 'TRACK_NEGATIVE_Z'
    camera.constraints["Track To"].up_axis = 'UP_Y'
    bpy.context.scene.camera = camera

    for area in bpy.context.screen.areas:
        if area.type == 'VIEW_3D':
            area.spaces[0].region_3d.view_perspective = 'CAMERA'
            break            
    return

def select_objects():
    for ob in bpy.context.scene.objects:
        ob.select = False
    for ob in bpy.context.visible_objects:
        ob.select = True
    return
#-----------------------------------------
clean_objects()
add_objects()
add_camera()
```

I guess "track to" feature should be able to adjust the angle of camera, how can I adjust my camera parameter to view full objects?

Comment: As far as I know only moving the camera farther away or lowering the focal length will do what you want. To prevent objects from disappearing as you move the camera away you can increase the end clipping of the camera.

Comment: I'd recommend going the other way.  Parent all "add" objects in scene without a parent to a single  empty.  Scale the empty to fit the camera. [Related](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/45146/how-to-find-all-objects-in-the-cameras-view-with-python)