# How to identify the object which are not visble from camera view though exist in a Blender scene. Using Blender Python API

Tags: python

[image]

Hi everyone. I doing some test in blender. I need to identify the object not visible from the camera view though it exists in the scene. I have tried bvh1.overlap(bvh2) and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57463072/how-do-i-know-if-an-object-is-inside-the-view-frustum-of-a-camera-in-blender-bp
To check whether the object is overlapping or inside the frustum. Even I tried the mesh.ray_cast from small cube to camera location using the given link: https://blenderartists.org/t/how-to-use-ray-cast/702131/3

when I am doing ray_cast from small_cube to camera I get True.
Please help me out and make me understand what I am missing or doing wrong.

Comment: Does [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/45324/42221) answer your question?

Comment: Dear @MartyFouts Thanks for the reply. I m new to Blender Python API. Let me try that and will update you soon. Can you please suggest to me where to seek more examples related to Blender Python API.

Comment: It the top bar it says "Search on Blender..."  You can type text in there to search for.  The text includes tags.  If you enter `[python]` and then some words describing what you are looking for, it will give you a list of python-tagged questions/answers containing those words.